# Bigdecimal userinput or double to Bigdecimal

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am creating a Currency converter using BigDecimal and now I am suck with an issue.

I have a user-defined number - "Amount" (this is the amount of currency you want to convert)

I am putting that userValue through the scanner class but I have only ever done this successfully with the following :

```java
int userInput = new scanner.nextint();
```

I would have loved userinput to be passed as a BigDecimal

but my understanding of java is very limited.

would you suggest converting the double to BigDecimal or is there a much simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to get user input as a `BigDecimal` then you can use one of `Scanner` class method [`nextBigDecimal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextBigDecimal()) To convert existing `double` to `BigDecimal` you can use `BigDecimal.valueOf()` method.

Code sample:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter BigDecimal");
        var number = scanner.nextBigDecimal();
        System.out.println("BigDecimal from user input: " + number);

        var doubleNumber = 2.15;
        var decimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(doubleNumber);
        System.out.println("Double converted to BigDecimal: " + decimal);
    }
```

Listing:

```
Enter BigDecimal
2,15
BigDecimal from user input: 2.15
Double converted to BigDecimal: 2.15

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Keep in mind that while converting `double` to `BigDecimal` you may loose some accuracy of data, because `double` is less accurate comparing to `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Thank you for this ill play around with it and try and get it to work my end

how do i mark as answered =) ?